# Get-Content file reading issues

Tags: powershell

I am trying to push a set of software to multiple machines on a domain using Powershell. I am able to only get the first line in the machinegroup.txt to behave as I expected it to. Every machine listed beyond the first line in the text file Just does not register. How do I get the script to read beyond the first line in the text file?

```
enter code here

#Variables for Software Local Machine Push
$computername = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Public\testdeploy\machinegroup.txt'
$sourcefile = "C:\Users\Public\testdeploy\file1.msi",
"C:\users\public\testdeploy\file2.msi",
"C:\users\public\testdeploy\file_push_2.ps1","C:\users\public\testdeploy\OrgInfo.json"

#This section will push the software
foreach ($computer in $computername) 
{}
$destinationFolder = "\\$computer\c$\users\Public\Downloads\Cisco"
#This section will copy the $sourcefile to the $destinationfolder. If the Folder does not exist it 
will create it.
if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder))
{
    New-Item $destinationFolder -Type Directory
}
Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder
```

Comment: Double check that `ForEach` loop.

Comment: Why are you not using a purpose-built tool for this, like SCCM or PSAppDeploy, vs doing this from scratch? [PSAppDeploy ToolKit](https://psappdeploytoolkit.com). Unless it's a learning/self-edification effort, don't frustrate yourself by doing it from scratch or working under the assumption that you are doing something new. Automated app deployment, has been a thing long before PowerShell ever existed, and because of that, many pre-built scripts/samples/solutions already exist. Use the So searhcbox above or your favorite search engine to find them.

Comment: @postanote I attempted the software deployment and upgrade via SCCM. However ,the older version failed to uninstall all registry keys and prevented SCCM from completing the push and wrecked 15 of the 20 attempts.  So, this "targeted" Solution was needed to place a second script on the local machines that automates the uninstall and cleanup.. The special condition here is that these are all machine needing VPN updates and all of them are remote. Luckily, my second script works exactly as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in an array with this `$computername` and this `$sourcefile`. Thus you cannot pass it the way you are doing. You have to enumerate/loop thru them.

So, something like this, keeping all comments in the comment block. Avoid commenting on the obvious. Your code should be written to be in plain English, Full cmdlet use, no aliases in scripts (they are fine in throw-away code, interactive stuff), self-explanatory, and self-documenting as possible.

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Remote application deployment
.DESCRIPTION
    Copy required apps from source to destination
.EXAMPLE
    Example of how to use this function/script/cmdlet
.EXAMPLE
    Another example of how to use this function/script/cmdlet
.NOTE
    More notes here
#>

$computernames = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Public\testdeploy\machinegroup.txt'

$sourcefile   = @(
                    'C:\Users\Public\testdeploy\file1.msi',
                    'C:\users\public\testdeploy\file2.msi',
                    'C:\users\public\testdeploy\file_push_2.ps1',
                    'C:\users\public\testdeploy\OrgInfo.json'
                 )

$computernames | 
ForEach {
    $destinationFolder = "\\$PSItem\c$\users\Public\Downloads\Cisco"

    if (-Not(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder))
    {New-Item -Path $destinationFolder -Type Directory}

    $sourcefile | 
    ForEach {Copy-Item -Path $PSItem -Destination $destinationFolder}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information and code edit. I will try this out now and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked exactly as I needed it to. Thank you so much :) !!!!!

Comment: Based on your above example, is there a way to execute the .ps1 copied to the destinations on each machine in $computernames in the same array? Or is this something better suited for PSappdeploy?

Comment: Yes, one is, in your use case is to create a scheduled task on the remote host to run the script at some point in the day after you've done the copy. Of course, setting that to run only once and when the user is logged on.

Comment: Interesting approach. I was trying to use an empty package with command line execution only to trigger script two on the remote machines. Just wasn't working. I will research that. Thank you again. –